# Detect when user has swiped left or right to go back or forth on WKWebView

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview

I am using a WKWebView and I allowed back and forward navigation gestures :

```
myWkWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
```

Now, the user has two ways to go back : either by pushing a button or by swiping left. The behaviors would be different, so I am wondering how I can know when a user has just swiped left / right so I can handle this.

I looked into WKNavigationDelegate reference ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/ ) but I couldn't find anything useful.

Any idea ?

**EDIT**

I forgot to say that I also tried to add swipe gesture recognizers, this way :

```
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyVC.respondToSwipeLeftOrRight(_:)))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyVC.respondToSwipeLeftOrRight(_:)))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
    myWkWebView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(swipeRight)
    myWkWebView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(swipeLeft)
```

But they are not triggered everytime I swipe left or right.

Answer (score 3):

```
private var currentBackForwardItem: WKBackForwardListItem?
private func handleBackForwardWebView(navigationAction: WKNavigationAction) {
    if navigationAction.navigationType == .BackForward {
        let isBack = webView.backForwardList.backList
            .filter { $0 == currentBackForwardItem }
            .count == 0

        if isBack {

        } else {

        }
    }

    currentBackForwardItem = webView.backForwardList.currentItem
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    handleBackForwardWebView(navigationAction)
    decisionHandler(.Allow)
}
```

Comment: Please note, that in a SinglePageApplication with a Framework like angular, there is only a route change and the WKWebView only fires its functions when a full page load happens. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47829963/how-can-i-detect-when-url-of-amp-page-changed-with-wkwebview Which means you will not get a method call here if you navigate in an angular or ionic application.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with your gesture recognizers, but you need to implement `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` method from `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` if you want to handle several gesture recognizers on single view:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for your answer, I have already implemented this method, the gesture recognizers are just "less sensitive" than the ones implemented internally within the `WKWebView`

Comment: I can assume that requireGestureRecognizerToFail methods causing problems with sensitivity. You can try to remove them, since shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer method should support all gestures.

Comment: Where does this go? In the ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that a SinglePageApplication wont work as Stefan Rein says we could incorporate the linked solution by checking the web view's gesture recognizers.

```objectivec
[self.webView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"URL" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
//....
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
  if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"URL"]) {    
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.webView.gestureRecognizers) {
      if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        if (((UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer).state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
          NSLog(@"Swiped!");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course if you have other gestures other than the two for forward and back then you might need to do more checks.