# How can I detect when url of amp page changed with WKWebview

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I'm developing simple web browser with WKWebview.
I can detect when url changed at SPA like trello with custom Javascript.

That way will not work In amp page. (Accelerated Mobile Pages of Google)
I tried put `print("webView.url")` to all of `WKNavigationDelegate` function
But I couldn't detect change of `amp page url`.

But `webView` has amp page url , I'd like to save amp page url to local store.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WKWebView function for detecting if the URL has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213185/wkwebview-function-for-detecting-if-the-url-has-changed)

Comment: ```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {  
print(webView.url)
print(navigationAction.request.url)
```
Not called in amp page

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Same issue. Unfortunately WKWebView only fires its functions when a full page load happens.

So what we have to do instead is use Key Value Observing on the WebKit.url property.

Looks something like this:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import WebKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.navigationDelegate = self

    self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
    self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress", options: .new, context: nil)

    self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: "https://google.com"))
  }

  override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == #keyPath(WKWebView.url) {
      print("### URL:", self.webView.url!)
    }

    if keyPath == #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress) {
      // When page load finishes. Should work on each page reload.
      if (self.webView.estimatedProgress == 1) {
        print("### EP:", self.webView.estimatedProgress)
      }
    }
  }
```

Each additional navigation in the wkWebkitView should cause a new combo of "### URL" and "### EP" to fire off.

Comment: can detect video player by observer add in WKWebView. can you help me for that my question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview i want to get the video url which play in WKWebView swift

Comment: awesome!!! thank you so much! All delegates are related to first-page loading, but this saved me.