# Implement webkit with swiftUI on macOS (And create a preview of a webpage)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, webkit, nsviewcontrollerrepresentable

I'm trying to create a menubar application which shows the inbox of this site. I would like to make an easy function that opens a small popup with the url of the item (without opening safari). An inbox item would look something like this

```swift
struct InboxItem: View {
    @State var MesgSite: String = "https://duckduckgo.com"
    @State private var showSafari = false    
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("some text")
        .background(SelectColor.opacity(0.5))
        .onLongPressGesture {
           //show preview of the MesgSite here
            self.SelectColor = .blue
            self.showSafari.toggle()
        }.popover(isPresented: self.$showSafari) {
            SafariPreview()
        }
    }
}

struct SafariPreview: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Display the webpage here")
            .padding()
        }.frame(maxWidth: 533, maxHeight: 300)
    }

}
```

<del>I would like to, when one longpresses on the item, it should make a preview of the associated webpage just like in the default mail app on macOS like so:</del>

> Got the popup working now

[image: Open a preview of the website]

I have tried adding a `wkwebview` as well as a `SafariView` in a `NSViewRepresentable`, however I got (among similar) the following error message using code from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336457/swiftui-wkwebview-detect-url-changing)

> `Use of undeclared type 'UIViewRepresentable'`

TIA!

### Edit:

The most basic version of the project can be found [here on github](https://github.com/ChielChiel/SE-Message-Test)

### Edit 2:

Gave more focus to the question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have also tried to come up with a solution. Since I couldn't find any documentation on this online whatsoever I'll give the solution that I've found by trial and error.

First, as it turns out `UI...` has its counterpart on macOS called `NS...`. Thus `UIViewRepresentable` would be `NSViewRepresentable` on macOS. Next I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347963/swiftui-wkwebview-cutting-off-page-content-on-macos-nsviewrepresentable) which had an example of a `WKWebview` on macOS. By combining that code with [this answer on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59018581/8902440) I could also detect the url change as well know when the view was done loading.

#### The SwiftUI WebView on macOS

This resulted in the following code. For clarity, I suggest putting it in a different file like `WebView.swift`:

First, import the needed packages:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import Combine
```

Then create a model that holds the data that you want to be able to access in your SwiftUI views:

```swift
class WebViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var link: String
    @Published var didFinishLoading: Bool = false
    @Published var pageTitle: String
    
    init (link: String) {
        self.link = link
        self.pageTitle = ""
    }
}
```

Lastly, create the `struct` with `NSViewRepresentable` that will be the HostingViewController of the `WebView()` like so:

```swift
struct SwiftUIWebView: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    public typealias NSViewType = WKWebView
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: WebViewModel

    private let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()
    public func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<SwiftUIWebView>) -> WKWebView {
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.uiDelegate = context.coordinator as? WKUIDelegate
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: viewModel.link)!))
        return webView
    }

    public func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<SwiftUIWebView>) { }

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(viewModel)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        private var viewModel: WebViewModel

        init(_ viewModel: WebViewModel) {
           //Initialise the WebViewModel
           self.viewModel = viewModel
        }
        
        public func webView(_: WKWebView, didFail: WKNavigation!, withError: Error) { }

        public func webView(_: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation: WKNavigation!, withError: Error) { }

        //After the webpage is loaded, assign the data in WebViewModel class
        public func webView(_ web: WKWebView, didFinish: WKNavigation!) {
            self.viewModel.pageTitle = web.title!
            self.viewModel.link = web.url?.absoluteString as! String
            self.viewModel.didFinishLoading = true
        }

        public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) { }

        public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }

    }

}
```

This code can be used as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        //Pass the url to the SafariWebView struct.
        SafariWebView(mesgURL: "https://stackoverflow.com/")
    }
}
struct SafariWebView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: WebViewModel

    init(mesgURL: String) {
        //Assign the url to the model and initialise the model
        self.model = WebViewModel(link: mesgURL)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        //Create the WebView with the model
        SwiftUIWebView(viewModel: model)
    }
}
```

#### Create a Safari Preview

So now we have this knowledge it is relatively easy to recreate the handy safari preview.

To have that, make sure to add `@State private var showSafari = false` (which will be toggled when you want to show the preview) to the view that will call the preview.

Also add the `.popover(isPresented: self.$showSafari) { ...` to show the preview

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSafari = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Press me to get a preview")
            .padding()
        }
        .onLongPressGesture {
            //Toggle to showSafari preview
            self.showSafari.toggle()
        }//if showSafari is true, create a popover
        .popover(isPresented: self.$showSafari) {
            //The view inside the popover is made of the SafariPreview
            SafariPreview(mesgURL: "https://duckduckgo.com/")
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `SafariPreview struct` will look like this:

```swift
struct SafariPreview: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: WebViewModel
    init(mesgURL: String) {
        self.model = WebViewModel(link: mesgURL)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        //Create a VStack that contains the buttons in a preview as well a the webpage itself
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                //The title of the webpage
                Text(self.model.didFinishLoading ? self.model.pageTitle : "")
                Spacer()
                //The "Open with Safari" button on the top right side of the preview
                Button(action: {
                    if let url = URL(string: self.model.link) {
                        NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Open with Safari")
                }
            }
            //The webpage itself
            SwiftUIWebView(viewModel: model)
        }.frame(width: 800, height: 450, alignment: .bottom)
            .padding(5.0)
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: macOS Safari webpage preview with swiftUI]

Answer (score 5):

Answer of Chiel is great!

But, possibly, someone search for html renderer view without full browser features

WORKS FOR MACOS

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: View {
    @Binding var html: String
    
    var body: some View {
        WebViewWrapper(html: html)
    }
}

struct WebViewWrapper: NSViewRepresentable {
    let html: String
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        nsView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

usage:

```
@State var text = "<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1><p><strong>hell</strong> yeah!</p></body></html>"
//......

TextField("", text: $text)
        
Divider()

WebView(html: $text)
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

[image]