# Why doesn't observeValueForKeyPath trigger in my webView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, webkit, observers

Since `webviewdidfinishload` has been deprecated and the `webKit` delegates don't seem to trigger when navigating to another `url` (from what I can see), I looked into using observer `forKeyPath`, like here:

[How can I detect when url of amp page changed with WKWebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47829963/how-can-i-detect-when-url-of-amp-page-changed-with-wkwebview/48273950)

And while this seems like a valid approach, I can't get the `observeValue` to trigger. At times it works, but most often it doesn't, and there doesn't seem to be any consistency.

```
- (void)setUpWebView {
    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.thisisnottherealurl.com"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    WKWebViewConfiguration *webViewConfig = [WKWebViewConfiguration new];

    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:webViewConfig];
    _webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    _webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _webView.alpha = 0.0f;
//    _webView.alpha = 1;

    [_webViewContainer addSubview:_webView];

    [self startLoadingAnimation];

    [_webView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_webViewContainer.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [_webView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_webViewContainer.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [_webView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_webViewContainer.rightAnchor].active = YES;
    [_webView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_webViewContainer.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [_webView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_webViewContainer.heightAnchor].active = YES;

    [_webView loadRequest:request];

    //IMPORTANT PART
    [_webView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"url" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior context:nil];
}
```

And then the `observeValue` part:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
     NSLog(@"OBSERVED");
}
```

Now, this doesn't trigger. Instead of observing `_webView` I have also tried `_webView.URL.absoluteString`. But still, it doesn't trigger. I have added alternative options like so: `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior` but still nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a better approach to this? Is there a `delegate` that actually trigger when navigating to another url link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method from WKNavigationDelegate of WKWebView.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
{
 NSURLRequest* request = navigationAction.request;
 if ([request.URL.urlString hasPrefix:@<Do ur checking here>])
{
 decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel); // Cancel the request
}
else 
{
decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow); // Allow the request.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't trigger when I click around. It only when the weView is loaded.

Comment: Can you tell us how are you navigating to another url? Try webViewConfiguration.dataDetectorTypes = WKDataDetectorTypeAll and navigate. This should call the delegate method. The documentation itself says so. "Decides whether to allow or cancel a navigation."

Comment: Well, it's just a web page like any else, so pressing different links and buttons takes the user to different sub urls. I added webViewConfiguration.dataDetectorTypes = WKDataDetectorTypeAll but nothing happens. The delegate just trigger (a lot of times) when the webView start, but then nothing.